# Michelson_v1_printer.unparse error with originate contract

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client

I am trying to use tezos client to deploy contract on alphanet but I get error
`Michelson_v1_printer.unparse`

Command:

```
tezos-client -l -A $TEZOS_NODE  originate contract controller_v6 for $MANAGER transferring 100 from $MANAGER running controller_v6.tz --init "(Pair $value {})"
```

Contract code:

```
let%entry createIdentity (iParam : key_hash ) storage = 
    (* Get the address of this contract *)
    let lControllerAddress = Contract.address(Contract.self()) in
    let lManager = tz1VmAgSPgwGVmXemXYSY24dZheQjVZYfRXS in
    (* Creating the proxy contract *)
    let (op, lProxyAddress) = 
        Contract.create 
            ~manager:lManager 
            ~delegate:None 
            ~spendable:false 
            ~delegatable:false 
            ~amount:100tz 
            ~storage:(iParam, lControllerAddress) 
            (contract Proxy) 
    in 
    let storage = storage.mOwner <- Map.add iParam lProxyAddress storage.mOwner in
    [op], (storage)
```

What does the error mean? Any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the full Michelson code, the entire controller_v6.tz file? (You provided some Liquidity .liq code.) Unfortunately this "unparse" error doesn't explain itself yet. We can find the cause but I'd like to have the exact Michelson causing the error first.

Comment: Also, `tezos-node --version` would be helpful if it works, or your tezos.git SHA if you know it.